# How to append an element into a existing array in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array in javascript

```
var myArr = {
    'textId':'123', 
    'type':'animal', 
    'content':'hi dog', 
    'expires':'27/10/2012' 
};

$.each(myArr, function(myArrArrKey, myArrArrValue){
    console.log( myArrArrValue );
});
```

The above console prints following values

```
123
app
hi app
27/10/2012
```

Now i am want to append an element to the existing array, i am trying to do like the below one

```
myArrValue.push({'status':'active'});
```

The above push throws following error

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'push'
```

Kindly help me how to append to that existing array element.
I want to print the array like

```
123
app
hi app
27/10/2012
active
```

Comment: That is an object, not an array. More importantly, your output does not seem to match your input in the first case.

Comment: this is a json object not an array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this isn't an array, it's an object!

```
var myArr = {
    'textId':'123', 
    'type':'animal', 
    'content':'hi dog', 
    'expires':'27/10/2012' 
};
```

this isn't necessary with jQuery

```
$.each(myArr, function(myArrArrKey, myArrArrValue){
    console.log( myArrArrValue );
});
```

easier would be

```
for ( var k in myArr ) {
    console.log( myArr[ k ];
}
```

to add new entries to your "array"

```
myArr[ 'foo' ] = 'bar';  // this is array notation
```

or

```
myArr.foo = 'bar';  // this is object notation
```

to remove entries from your "array"

```
delete myArr[ 'foo' ];
```

or

```
delete myArr.foo;
```

FYI:
`myArrValue.push({'status':'active'});` wont work. myArrValue isn't the "array" itself and also not an array having the method `push`.
If it would be an array the result would be, that your latest entry is the whole an object `{'status':'active'}`

Answer (score 4):

Just do this.

```
myArr.status = 'active'
```

or

```
myArr["status"] = 'active'
```

Your `myArr` is an `Object` not an `Array`..

`push` function is available to an `Array` variable.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in the error... you have an object, not an array. Use object notation

```
myArr.status='active'
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use:

```
myArrValue.status = 'active';
```

but be aware that what you are using is an **object**, not an array. Another way to add properties to an object is:

```
object[key] = value;
```

Answer (score 2):

this a json object not array push would for an array
for json you do

```
myObj.NewProp = 123;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for the kicks of it..

```
function push( obj ) {
    var prop;
    for ( prop in obj ) {
        this[prop] = obj[prop];
    }
    return this;
}
```

Your object, remember to assing the push method.

```
var obj = {
    a: "a",
    b: "b",
    push: push
};
```

And the push:

```
obj.push({
    c: "c",
    d: "d"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
myArr["status"] = 'active';
```

or

```
myArr.status ='active';
```